# Got 220 MB space free but still not able to download apps

Tags: internal-storage

I have a second gen MOTO -E . I have 220 MB free in internal storage but I can't download apps of even 3 MB What should I do ?

Answer (score 1):

To be able to download apps in the Play Store you will need at least 510mb available or 10% of the internal memory. Also depends on the size of the app you download. The Android OS uses the internal memory also to RAM purposes so is very relative the available space. Try to clear cache and data from GPStore, GPServices, Reset Apps Defaults and also remove some unused apps.

Also check the link provided by bmdixon

Comment: Is that the *minimum* of 510MB or 10%, or the *maximum* of 510MB or 10%?  BTW, do you happen to have a source of that info?

Comment: You need to have a minimum of 510mb available OR you need to have at least 10% free of the total amount depending on the device.

Comment: lol... If your device has 32GB of RAM, would you need 510MB or 3.2GB?  If your device has 2GB of RAM, would you need 510MB or 200MB?  IOW, is it the *minimum* or *maximum* of the two values?  Do you have any source for the info?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problems recently and cause was app2id. Uninstalling that and any other similar app might help. Also clean cache of play store and play services.